# Entity Framework AddTo function inconsistency?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Let me describe the behavior I get:

- Load a user from the database: this means the user is attached to the context
- Create a new Object C:

  - C tempC = new C();
  - tempC.User = previously loaded user;
  - Context.AddToCSet( tempC );
  - The last line throws an exception because the object was added to the context when the property user was set.

but if I do the following:

- Load a user from the database: this means the user is attached to the context
- Create a new Object C:

  - C tempC = new C();
  - tempC.User = previously loaded user;
  - Context.SaveChange();
- Create a new Object E which has a relationship with Object C.

  - E tempE = new E();
  - tempE.C = previously created C;
  - Context.AddToESet( tempE );

it *doesn't* throw an exception. I was expecting an exception because by then C is attached to the context, which should be the same case as the first example. But it isn't. Why, and what can I do to have some consistency?

I am planning on checking the state of the object (EntityState == Detached) before adding it to the set, but I figured I must be doing something wrong to begin with.

Comment: Not sure, but some code showing what you're doing could help here.

Comment: What is the relationship between the Object C and a User object?  Is it 1 to 1?  1 to many?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that there is a 1 to Many relationship between `User` and `C`, you may want to use a different syntax to add a `C` to the parent `User`.  Instead of `tempC.User = previously loaded user;` you probably want to add the `tempC` as a child of `User`.  Here is what I mean:

```
C tempC = new C(); 
(previously created user).C.Add(tempC);
Context.AddToCSet(tempC);
```